Elasticsearch allocate system indices shards to specific nodes
Elasticsearch version: 7.17.14
kubernetes version: 1.28 (AWS EKS)
Deployed using ECK Operator
We have deployed our Elasticsearch cluster in AWS using kubernetes.
Problem statement:
we have combination of spot and on-demand instances for data nodes, which are scaled using keda. some of the shards(primary and replica) of system indices are getting allocated to spot nodes.
During scale down these shards are getting lost.
Question:

Is there a possibility to ignore those system indices and remove them?
If 1st is not possible then can we allocate these shards to a group of nodes that we specify.
Can we replicate these shards to each and every nodes.

Solutions that we have tried:

Updating settings for system indices to set shard awareness. (which didn't work because settings can not be updated for these indices)

Updating settings for system indices to set shard awareness. (which didn't work because settings can not be updated for these indices)
Expectations:

If data nodes are scaled up and down, the system shards should not be lost.


Can you provide the index name example, please?
Maybe you could use the fact, that most if not all, system indices are supposed to be allocated in the "data_content" tier (you can see this in the index settings) So you can try to remove the data_content role from the "Spot" nodes. But this means that you need to define your indices to the data_hot or any other tier (depending on your cluster architecture).
